# Dynamically add items in zabbix template

Tags: amazon-kinesis, zabbix

I have a Kinesis Stream with 10 shards. I want to create a single host on Zabbix by the name of the stream eg: Some_Kinesis_stream. 
In the template I want to dynamically create items like "Some_Kinesis_stream..." for every shard that gets spawned. Is there a way to detect a new shard and create items like above?

I think some discovery rules need to used to trigger the template edition. I don't have a clear view on the implementation.

Also, there is no Zabbix Agent.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom [low level discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#creating_custom_lld_rules) (LLD) for that. In the LLD rule, have a prototype like `Some_Kinesis_stream[{#SHARD}]`, and send JSON with all the streams as per the example in the documentation.

Comment: Could you please add some more details on creating the LLD for this requirement. Maybe a snapshot of a similar configuration.

Comment: Please see the linked documentation page, there is an example LLD JSON and a Perl example of generating such JSON.